# Openlayers bbox strategy

Tags: openlayers-3

I have bbox strategy for one source of data. Code looks like this:

```
bbox: function newBboxFeatureSource(url, typename) {
    return new ol.source.Vector({
        loader: function (extent) {
            let u = `${url}&TYPENAME=${typename}&bbox=${extent.join(",")}`;

            $.ajax(u).then((response) => {
                this.addFeatures(
                    geoJsonFormat.readFeatures(response)
                );
            });
        },
        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
    });
},
```

I works fine but... When I pan/move the map then this *loader* is calling again and add another features which fit to new box. But there is a lot of duplicates then because some of new features are just the same as old.
So I wanted first clear all features using `this.clear()` before add new features but when I add this command then *loader* is running all the time and I have "infinitive loop". Do you know why? How can I disable loading new features after calling `this.clear()`?

edit:

my response with features looks like this:

> { "type": "FeatureCollection", "crs": { "type": "name", "properties":
>   { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857" } },
>                                                                                    "features": [ { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ogc_fid": "2",
>   "name": "AL" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon" , "coordinates":
>   [ [ [ ... ] ] ] } }, { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ogc_fid":
>   "3", "name": "B" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon" ,
>   "coordinates": [ [ [ ...] ] ] } } ..... and so on

I've removed coordinates because there was too many of them.

My features are generated by mapserver and are configured in .map file which looks like this:

```
LAYER
    NAME "postcode_area_boundaries"
    METADATA
        "wfs_title"                 "Postcode area boundaries"
        "wfs_srs"                   "EPSG:3857"
        "wfs_enable_request"        "*"
        "wfs_getfeature_formatlist" "json"
        "wfs_geomtype"              "multipolygon"
        "wfs_typename"              "postcode_area_boundaries"
        "wms_context_fid"           "id"
        "wfs_featureid"             "id"
        "gml_featureid"             "id"
        "gml_include_items"         "id,postarea,wkb_geometry"
        "gml_postarea_alias"        "name"
        "ows_featureid"             "id"
        "tinyows_table"             "postcode_area_boundaries"
        "tinyows_retrievable"       "1"
        "tinyows_include_items"     "id,postarea,wkb_geometry"
    END
    TYPE POLYGON
    STATUS ON
    CONNECTIONTYPE POSTGIS
    CONNECTION "..."
    DATA "wkb_geometry FROM postcode_area_boundaries USING UNIQUE id"
    DUMP TRUE
END
```

Comment: Do you have unique ids on your features? If you get your features from a geoserver or any server check if they have unique ids, if not create the unique ids on your server and the problem should dissapear. Also, cosider using a url function instead of a loader.

Comment: @pavlos I've inherited this code by previous developer. Changing loader into url function  doesn't resolve problem. About unique ids: I've updated my questions and added example of feature response. I have unique column in db which is called `ogc_fid`.

Comment: Are you able to switch `ogc_fid` to just `fid`????

Comment: @pavlos to do this I will have to change a lot of js code... there is also hidden logic. But ok, I will try. Thank you for your answers. I will let you know when I do this :)

Comment: Just add a new column called `fid` within your DB, populate it with `ogc_fid`  and do a reload on your geoserver. Good luck

Comment: sorry for that, seems that the property should be `id` and not `fid` check the last post from here -->https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/3812

Comment: @pavlos I've used `fid` and it didn't work - problem the same. I've also used `id` and still the same.

Comment: @pavlos Ok, your link get me sth. When I call feature.setId("foo") I can see that feature has some field called `i` set to `foo`. When I didn't not call `setId` then this `i` field is `undefined`. So this is not about column name in DB but about feature ID which is not setted. How can I set this feature id some other way than manually in js?

Comment: you have to set the id outside of the properties. `"features": [ { "type": "Feature","id":"2", "properties": { "ogc_fid": "2", `

Comment: @pavlos but I do not generate response. My features are generated by mapserver and are configured in .map file. I've edit my question and added example of that .map file

Comment: Then I am afraid your only option is to set the id manually on js. OL3 somehow need to distinguish features , so it is designed to do it using the id.

Comment: @pavlos Ah. That's a shame :( I thought it can be done by mapserver but I couldn't find any info about this. Anyway thank you once more, now I know what is the reason of this duplicates :) If you want you can write answer and I will set it as a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the discussion and answer the initial question:

The features sent by the server need an attribute called id, which must be unique and the same for the feature on every request.

```
{type: "Feature", id: "some-wfs.1234", properties: { "ogc_fid": 2, ...
```

See [this GitHub Issue](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/3812#issuecomment-255096398) for the original comment of ahocevar.

In GeoServer this can be achieved if you set an identifier in your layer.
I guess there is something similar to set in MapServer.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on @bennos comment: you can expose the fid in Mapserver using the FORMATOPTION USE_FEATUREID=true as described in: https://mapserver.org/output/ogr_output.html

**USE_FEATUREID=true/false**

Starting from MapServer v7.0.2. Defaults to false. Include feature ids in the generated output, if the ows_featureid metadata key is set at the layer level. The featureid column to use should be an integer column. Useful if you need to include an “id” attribute to your geojson output. Use with caution as some OGR output drivers may behave strangely when fed with random FIDs.

```
    OUTPUTFORMAT
      NAME "application/json"
      DRIVER "OGR/GEOJSON"
      MIMETYPE "application/json"
      FORMATOPTION "FORM=SIMPLE"
      FORMATOPTION "FILENAME=ol-query.json"
      FORMATOPTION "STORAGE=memory"
      FORMATOPTION "USE_FEATUREID=true"
    END
```